# How to speed-up complete reproduction of an whole experiment in psychopy

Tags: performance, time, psychopy

I have a complex and time-consuming experiment to launch in pychopy. Do you have any recommendations to speed up the reproduction of the whole experiment? I would like to analyze faster the stimuli and order they have been presented on the spreadsheet they are exported to.

Please just be explicit in the case, if you would use some specific code and where you recommend inserting the routine/component.

Thanks

Comment: Such an open-ended question, with no specific programming details, isn't suitable for the StackOverflow format. I'd suggest you take it to the dedicated PsychoPy forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org, which allows for more interactive discussion. But I'd suggest being more specific and detailed in your question even there. e.g. it is not at all clear what you mean by "reproduction", and whether this question is actually more about analysis than running an experiment.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. By reproduction, I mean presentation/launching the experiment itself from the start to the end. I didn't add any detail because I thought this kind of issue might be faced in a very standard way (by adding some specific component in a specific routine). Let's pretend you might want to run your whole experiment (from the beginning to the end) and you want this to last 1 sec. What would you do?

Comment: The question as posed doesn't make sense. Time is inherent to the specification of an experiment in PsychoPy - it simply can't arbitrarily be compressed to some tiny value. And fundamentally, PsychoPy's Builder generated scripts are tied to the hardware being used - certain code needs to run on every screen refresh (typically every 16.7 ms for a 60 Hz display). That granularity alone means that an experiment can't be arbitrarily compressed - an experiment (on a 60 Hz display at least) is a sum of discrete 16.7 ms epochs, rather than a continuous process.